# render page without footer yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying render page in grid view, it was success but the footer is show on the column i render, how to remove its

This is the colomn `GridView` i write :

```
 [   'format' => 'raw',
     'value' => function($model) { return "<p class='feedback'>". $model->KOMENTAR  ."</p><br><p class='feedback-date'>". $model->TANGGAL ."</p><hr><div id='replay-". $model->ID_KOMENTAR."'><ul></ul><div id='replay-column'></div></div>";},
 ],
```

I render the page inside div `class="replay-column"`

This the following js i made for rendering page when i click button:

```
$("#replay-to-"+ID_KOMENTAR).on("click", function(){
        $.get('index.php?r=feedback/feedbacktest',null, function(data){
            $('#replay-column').append(data);
        });
});
```

And this the controller :

```
    public function actionFeedbacktest(){
       echo $this->render('feedback_test');
    }
```

Comment: To load a partial page through ajax there is a method [renderAajx](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#renderAjax%28%29-detail). And if you want to generate the html with the validation code (js , if the page part have any active form ) , then use [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial%28%29-detail)